# DbUpdateException violation of Unique Key

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller

I have a function which edits a record in a grid, the data in this grid is retrieved from my database and only 1 column is editable. When trying to edit this record in my database based on the edited record I get an error that I'm violating the unique key. The column that is editable is not unique nor a key, and the values of `BinLocation_Item item` match the values of the database.

Edit: It seems like my application is trying to delete a row by using `WHERE BatchId = null` instead of `WHERE BatchId IS NULL` which is causing this problem.

Error:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
>
> SqlException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UC_BIB'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BinLocation_Item'. The duplicate key value is (3, 9642, NULL).

Code:

```
public ActionResult submitLocItem(BinLocationItemModel lines, int? PID, int? LineNum)
{
  dbEntity.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;      
  BinLocation_Item item = dbEntity.BinLocation_Item.Where(i => i.BinLocationId == lines.BinLocationId && i.ItemId == lines.ItemId && i.BatchId == lines.BatchID).FirstOrDefault();
  PickListLine picklistline = dbEntity.PickListLine.Where(i => i.PickID == PID && i.LineNum == LineNum).FirstOrDefault();

  picklistline.PickedQuantity = picklistline.PickedQuantity + lines.PickedStock;

  item.StockAvailable = lines.StockAvailable - lines.PickedStock;
  dbEntity.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
  dbEntity.SaveChanges();

  return View();
}
```

Comment: The error says it all, you are trying to add an Item with the same Primary Key as one that exists in the Database, it also gives you the duplicate key value  (3, 9642, NULL).

Comment: I intend to update the record not insert a new one, however it seems like my code tries to insert a new row (to replace the old?) at the moment. Any idea how I could properly update my record?

Comment: You have unique key defined for three columns and I think that's why you have this error coz the table has already a combination of values `3.3642,NULL` for those columns and as part of update operation the row  getting updated is having the same value combination for those columns.

Comment: In SQL Server updates to Primary Keys are internally handled as delete + insert, hence the "Cannot **insert** duplicate key". Other posters have explained why you are getting the error in the first place.

Comment: Yes I understand that however it's not a primary key just unique and I don't understand why it can't delete and insert a new one (it works if I do it manually in management studio).

Comment: After checking it a bit more on management studio it seems like visual studio uses a `WHERE BatchId = null` instead of `WHERE BatchId IS NULL` and that causes the row to remain undeleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my code to this did the trick, deleting the entry first and then adding it when a value is null.

```
  if(item.BatchId == null)
  {
    dbEntity.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
    dbEntity.SaveChanges();
    dbEntity.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
  }
  else
  {
    dbEntity.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
  }

  item.StockAvailable = lines.StockAvailable - lines.PickedStock;
  dbEntity.Entry(picklistline).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;      
  dbEntity.SaveChanges();

  return View();
```